# Arrow functions vs anonymous functions for Jest test case, setup, and teardown

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I've gathered that the [Jest documentation](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html) leans heavily on using arrow functions to define test cases, setup functions, and teardown functions. However, it looks like there is undocumented support for sharing a `this` context between test cases, setup, and teardown functions.

I prefer the arrow function style as it works better with static analysis and relies less on an assumption of what will be contained in the `this` context.

The pattern the docs seem to suggest:

```
describe('a test suite', () => {
  let shared;

  beforeEach(() => {
    shared = someInitializer();
  });

  test('a test case', () => {
    expect(shared).not.toBeUndefined();
  });
});
```

An alternate, undocumented pattern:

```
describe('a test suite', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    this.shared = someInitializer();
  });

  test('a test case', function () {
    expect(this.shared).not.toBeUndefined();
  });
});
```

Is this a holdover API from Jasmine? Is it a good practice or is it in danger of going away in future versions?

Comment: IMHO the first pattern seems easier to read.

Comment: Only the framework designers can answer that for sure. If the latter isn't documented, you shouldn't believe it will stick around. At the very least, it's definitely an indication from the developers that they prefer the former.

Comment: The former style is clearer about scoping. As you indicated, it is an undocumented holdover from Jasmine.